# How to reverse a list then use the reversed list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to reverse a list in Haskell, and then use the reversed list and do some work on it, but I don't know how, since Haskell picks up the third line and ignores my last line of code

**Note: I know I have pattern match overlap but I don't know how to fix it.**

This is what I have :

```
test :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
test _ [] = []
test _ (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]
test func (x:xs)
```

I  tried to use the `where` clause like this:

```
test :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
test _ [] = []
test func (x:xs)
    | some code here
    | some code here 
    where test _ (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]
```

But it does not look like it accepts it.

Comment: This question is not clear to me. What is the first parameter for? Why can't you simply use `reverse myList` for reversing? E.g. `let reversed = reverse myList in somehowUseResult reversed`.

Comment: Ate you sure you need `++[x]`? Does it fall under "reverse" part or under "do some work on it" part?

Comment: Instead of `reverse xs ++ [x]`, use `reverse (x : xs)`. Note that this does nothing to the list `(x:xs)`, aside from reverse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to reverse the list before further processing is to use a helper function:

```
func f xs = func' f (reverse xs)
  where
    func' _ [] = ...
    func' f (x:xs) = ...
```

(Note that reversing the empty list is a no-op, so you don't need to handle it specially in `func`.)

Comment: thanks man thats exactly what i needed and after the processing on the reverse list if i want to reverse the list again to show as output ? @Rein Henrichs

Comment: @NimaFarahani `reverse (func' f (reverse xs))`

Comment: @NimaFarahani this is a nice place to use composition: `func f = reverse . func' f . reverse`

Comment: thats awesome ! @Rein Henrichs

Answer (score 1):

#### remark:

as @chi just pointed out there is something fishy with the types/function

So you either want to *filter* or *use* the resulting map - I assumed the later (as you talked about it) but your signature suggests the former.

I'll edit the post and put on the first version as well

---

When you do your pattern matching like this:

```
test _ (x:xs)
test func (x:xs)
```

then both lines will match the same thing - the only difference is that in
the later case you named the first parameter (`func`) while in the first
you say *I don't need the function*

And as Haskell matches from top to bottom you will never see the last line
and so you will never get to the right-side of it

so

```
test :: ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> b
test f []     = f []
test f (x:xs) = f (reverse xs ++ [x])
```

or (the filter version)

```
test :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
test _ []     = []
test f (x:xs) = filter f (reverse xs ++ [x])
```

would have worked (although the deconstruction into `(x:xs)` and even the
first case are not really needed as @foo remarked)

---

The idea with the `where` was a good step but you try to mix it with pattern matching the list (you *don't* have to here at all - `reverse` will do it for you):

```
test :: ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> b
test f xs = f xs'
    where xs' = reverse xs
```

or *filter* version:

```
test :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
test f xs = filter f xs'
    where xs' = reverse xs
```

of course once you have this you might see that you can use
composition too:

```
test f xs = f (reverse xs) = (f . reverse) xs
```

or *filter* version

```
test f xs = filter f (reverse xs) = (filter f . reverse) xs
```

so that you can write

```
test f = f . reverse
```

or *filtered*

```
test f = filter f . reverse
```

instead too

**btw:** here you can see what I meant by

> just put your guards in whatever `f` is

in my comment as if you implement the first version then you get the second by just replacing `f` with `filter g` where `g` is your guard

Comment: i understand your code but it doesnt fix the problem, the point here is, im trying to reverse the list i get then apply the guards, so when you do test f     xs = f xs'
    where xs' = reverse xs it is not going to apply the guards anymore

Comment: just put your *guards*  in whatever `f` is - but maybe I get you wrong - why don't you just post what you are really trying to do? In your first *try* you did not have any *guards* at all btw

Comment: Note that `f :: a->Bool` does not take a list. Either the type of the OP is wrong, or the OP means entirely something else.

Comment: @chi true ... I completely missed this sorry (my bad) - I even copy&pasted ... doh

Comment: ok so here is what im trying to do @Carsten . so my second input will be a list, i need to reverse that list first, then with the answer which is the reversed list , check on some guards conditions, for ex: if i have my second input as [1,2,3,4,5] , i need to reverse it first so i get [5,4,3,2,1] then check if this reversed list have an odd number at the second index, hopefully this clarifies abit

Comment: this fit's in just fine if you use the *unfiltered* variant (`test f = f . reverse`)  with `f xs = odd (xs !! 1)`: `test (\xs -> odd (xs !! 1)) [1..5]` yields `False`, same with `[1..4]` yields `True`